# intercept a log from winstonjs and inject arguments

Tags: javascript, express, winston

Is it possible to inject an argument into a log such as error, debug or info using the winston configuration (createLogger)?

I'd like to be able to intercept the log and inject an object into each log

Comment: Sounds like something you could accomplish using a [custom formatter](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#creating-custom-formats). What have you tried?

Comment: thank you kindly @Philisonstrike that seems to have worked

Answer (score 0):

solution I used

```html
export const correlationInjection = winston.format(info => {
  info.correlationId = correlator.getId();
  return info;
});
```

Thank you Phillisonstrike